# Plugins Page invisible / white

Tags: plugins, php, bug

I found a lot of posts about the white-screen-of-death, but as far as I can tell, that's not my problem. Whenever I open the backend, everything is fine until I enter the plugins section. The secondary Navigation and the content on the rigth are completely blank, however if I move the mouse over it, or if I just select everything it becomes visible again.

The problem only occurs from within firefox. I already deleted all local files (cache etc.) and I checked the plugins.php for changes. But oddly enough I was not able to find any local explanation.

Is there any known bug that could cause these blank parts?

Answer (score 1):

### The Bug

…is well known, but it's not a bug. It's an **Error**, that you *don't* display.

### The Fix

Move into your `~/wp-config.php` file. Then add

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

and read your **Error** message.